# hash map, remove duplicates but also store # of original occurances. java

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I have a java hash map which is used for generating "rules" learned by inference. For example the input might look like:

```
'prevents'('scurvy','vitamin C').
'contains'('vitamin C','orange').
'contains'('vitamin C','sauerkraut').
'isa'('fruit','orange').
'improves'('health','fruit').
```

and the output might look like this:

```
prevents(scurvy, orange).
prevents(scurvy, sauerkraut).
improves(health, orange).
```

For a small test everything works quite well but in my actual data set I have many instances of identical rules. I want to somehow store the number of occurrences for each rule and write that to a file, along with the number of times it's been seen, since I think that can be some kind of naive confidence measure for the likelihood the rule is a good one.

At this juncture I store sentences like this:

```
public class Sentence {
private String verb;
private String object;
private String subject;
public Sentence(String verb, String object, String subject ){
this.verb = verb;
this.object = object;
this.subject = subject;
}
public String getVerb(){ return verb; }
public String getObject(){ return object; }
public String getSubject(){ return subject; }
public String toString(){
return verb + "(" + object + ", " + subject + ")";
}
}
```

The hash map construct:

```
public class Ontology {
private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
/*
 * The following maps store the relation of a string occurring
 * as a subject or object, respectively, to the list of Sentence
 * ordinals where they occur.
 */
private Map<String,List<Integer>> subject2index = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String,List<Integer>> object2index = new HashMap<>();
/*
 * This set contains strings that occur as both,
 * subject and object. This is useful for determining strings
 * acting as an in-between connecting two relations. 
 */
private Set<String> joints = new HashSet<>();
public void addSentence( Sentence s ){
// add Sentence to the list of all Sentences
sentences.add( s );
// add the Subject of the Sentence to the map mapping strings
// occurring as a subject to the ordinal of this Sentence
List<Integer> subind = subject2index.get( s.getSubject() );
if( subind == null ){
   subind = new ArrayList<>();
    subject2index.put( s.getSubject(), subind );
}
subind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );
// add the Object of the Sentence to the map mapping strings
// occurring as an object to the ordinal of this Sentence
List<Integer> objind = object2index.get( s.getObject() );
if( objind == null ){
    objind = new ArrayList<>();
    object2index.put( s.getObject(), objind );
}
objind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );
// determine whether we've found a "joining" string
if( subject2index.containsKey( s.getObject() ) ){
    joints.add( s.getObject() );
}
if( object2index.containsKey( s.getSubject() ) ){
    joints.add( s.getSubject() );
}
}
public Collection<String> getJoints(){
return joints;
}
public List<Integer> getSubjectIndices( String subject ){
return subject2index.get( subject );
}
public List<Integer> getObjectIndices( String object ){
return object2index.get( object );
}
public Sentence getSentence( int index ){
return sentences.get( index );
}
}
```

and finally the code that determines the rules:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Ontology ontology = new Ontology();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)','(.*?)'\\)"); 
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if( m.matches() ) {
        String verb    = m.group(1);
        String object  = m.group(2);
        String subject = m.group(3);
        ontology.addSentence( new Sentence( verb, object, subject ) );
    }
}

for( String joint: ontology.getJoints() ){
    for( Integer subind: ontology.getSubjectIndices( joint ) ){
        Sentence xaS = ontology.getSentence( subind );
        for( Integer obind: ontology.getObjectIndices( joint ) ){
            Sentence yOb = ontology.getSentence( obind );
            Sentence s = new Sentence( xaS.getVerb(),
                                       xaS.getObject(),
                                       yOb.getSubject() );
            System.out.println( s );
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there some kind of fast and efficient way to eliminate duplicates from this hash map, keeping only one instance for each unique rule and simultaneously associating the new index with the number of identical instances of that rule that we had observed in the original map?

I want to eliminate the duplicate 'rules' after the sentences have been processed. But only after I have a chance to count the frequency with which each rule has occurred and saving it as a value associated with the unique rule that I end up keeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest some changes to your data model. You can quite easily store the number of times a sentence occurs in a `Map` as follows:

```
Map<Sentence, Integer> sentenceCount = new HashMap<>();
```

This relies on implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods for `Sentence`. It automatically eliminates duplicates by using `Sentence` as the key.

You can add new sentences to it as follows:

```
public addSentence(Sentence sentence) {
    if (!sentenceCount.containsKey(sentence))
        sentenceCount.put(sentence, 0);
    sentenceCount.put(sentence, sentenceCount.get(sentence) + 1);
}
```

Now you no longer need your `sentences` list because you can get the set of sentences using `sentenceCount.keySet()`.

If you need the maps from subject and object to sentences then I don't suggest you use an index: that is an error prone approach. Instead I suggest you make them direct maps:

```
Map<String, Set<Sentence>> subjectMap;
Map<String, Set<Sentence>> objectMap;
```

You can use this to find, say, the number of times a certain subject appears:

```
subjectMap.get("subject").stream().mapToInt(sentenceCount::get).sum();
```

Comment: hmm, I think that can work, though I'd be storing the rules, not the sentences, but one issue is, how to track the number of times that a potential addition of a rule is refused because it already exists in the map? and how to link that number to the rule it's associated with?

Comment: That's exactly what the `sentenceCount` map is for. The key is the sentence (maybe it should be rule as you say) and the value is the number of times it has occurred.

Comment: It seems like you think I should replace addSentence in the OP with your code there, but in the OP addSentence it also finds the rules, which is to say, what I'm really looking for is a system to learn "rules" by inference from input data, i.e. contains(vitamin c, oranges), prevents(scurvy, vitamin c) would yeild the output prevents(scurvy, oranges)

Comment: My code was intended to answer the question as stated: how to avoid duplicates and store the number of instances. Naturally you would need to extend the code to implement your learning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Guava, you can use an implementation of [Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset). The example in the user guide sounds reasonably similar to your requirements.